# Input's "for" attribute not redirecting to input box

Tags: html

I have a weird html problem.

I have a code like:

```
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name="username" type="text"/>
```

But when I click on the label text Username I am not "redirected" into the input text field. By redirection I mean that the blinking cursor appears inside the input field and I can start writing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To follow up on @SudipPal's answer - the `for` attribute references an `id` attribute, not the `name` attribute, hence why your markup doesn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For in label refers to an id:

```
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input name="username" id="username" type="text"/>
```

More: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1

Answer (score 2):

The text box also needs a value for id, so use one in the text box like this:

```
<input name="username" id="username" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score -2):

in Label for you need input's id not name so, mention input id

try this...

```
 <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" type="text"/>
```

hope it works for u!

Comment: No, you should not *replace* the `name` attribute but just *add* an `id` attribute. The `name` attribute has its own role, which is essential in normal usage (otherwise the field contents will be lost on form submission).